# apache mod_rewrite regex problem with multiple parameter

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite, parameters

Regular expressions have always been my pet peeves. Every time I think that I finally got it I have a new problem !

I want to catch url like this :

```
http://www.mydomain.com/boutique/blabla-1/bla-bla2/99/104
http://www.mydomain.com/boutique/blabla1/99
```

and eventually :

```
http://www.mydomain.com/boutique/blabla-1/bla-bla2/product1/99/104/55/
```

after a lot of tries and errors I came up with this which seems to work with http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ but not in apache

```
^.*/boutique/([a-zA-Z-]*)(/?[a-zA-Z-]*)/?([0-9]*)/?([0-9]*)/?$   boutique.php?c1=$3&c2=$4
```

(I was only working with the first two url so far)

MY apache rewrite log debug files are helpless :

> pass through /Users/iko/Sites/mysite/boutique.php

I'm only interrested in getting the ids. Any help we'll be welcomed !

Thank you.

Comment: What information do you need from that URLs?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^boutique/(?:[a-zA-Z][\w-]*/){1,3}/(\d+)(?:/(\d+)(?:/(\d+))?)?/?$ boutique.php?c1=$1&c2=$2&c3=$3
```

Comment: Thank you. I had to tweak it a little seems that the passive group don't work so what I came up with is 

boutique.php/([a-zA-Z-]*)(/?[a-zA-Z-]*/?){1,3}([0-9]*)/?([0-9]*)/?([0-9]*)/?$  boutique.php?c1=$3&c2=$4&p=$5 [L]

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to write a rule for each type as I find it clearer to read (especially if htaccess is a bugbear of yours)

i.e.

```
### Rewrite rule for /boutique/blabla-1/bla-bla2/99/104
RewriteRule ^boutique/([a-z0-9-]+)/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) boutique.php?c1=$3&c2=$4
```

To explain the different bits 
([a-z0-9-]+) is basically all lowercase letters, numbers and hyphens.
Similarily ([0-9]+) is just for numbers and hyphens

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you. in my case, as the number of parameters is fluid (between 1 and 3) I had to mark the slashes as optionnal